# C programming array swap

Tags: c, swap

I have been trying to do this for 4 hours with no luck and I really need to have it done. It is my school's task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char strings[5][5][5][5][5];
    char *temp[5];

    int b[5];
    int a[5];

    int x;
    int i;
    int z;

    int a_value;
    int b_value;

    //get 5 strings from the input
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%s", strings[i]);
    }

    //Get 5 numbers from the input
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        scanf("%d %d", & b[x], & a[x]);
        //printf("B is %d and A is %d\n", b[x], a[x]);

        a_value = a[x];
        b_value = b[x];
        temp[b_value] = strings[a_value];

        //If the values of a and b are equal to -1 denote the operation (end it)
        if (b[x] == -1 && a[x] == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }


    //Get the swapped values
    for (z = 0; z<=x; z++) {
        printf("%s\n", temp[z]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
aadf
bazz
abkt
bbaa
zzzz
1 3
0 4
3 2
-1 -1
```

The output is supposed to be like this

```
zzzz
bbaa
bazz
abkt
aadf
```

What I get is this

```
zzzz
bbaa
abkt
```

So everything works fine and strings get replaced based on that but the problem is that if `b` and `a` are not given so the swapped value should be the normal value and I don't know how to do it.

**The task exactly says:**

Read 5 strings from standard input and put them in an array. Each string is 4 characters length. Then prepare a function, that swaps i-th and j-th elements of the array. Indexes of i and j are given as standard input as two numbers separated by space. There can be more than one operations - each swap operation is separated by new line. Values -1 and -1 denote the end of operations. Print strings separated by new line.

Please help me and thanks ;)

Comment: why table with fifth dimension?

Comment: I really have no clue what to do.

Comment: you have `char strings[5][5][5][5][5];` Why on earth do you assigne a 4-dimensional array to a 1-dimentional one? `temp[b_value] = strings[a_value];`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's you code, corrected and optimized:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char strings[5][5];
    char temp[4];
    int x,y;

    //get 5 strings from the input
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      scanf("%s", strings[i]);
    }

    do{
        scanf("%d %d", & x, & y);
        // Assign string[x] to temp
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            temp[i] = strings[x][i];
        }
        // Assign string[y] to string[x]
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            strings[x][i] = strings[y][i];
        }
        // Assign temp to string[y]
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            strings[y][i] = temp[i];
        }
    }while(x!=-1 && y!=-1);


    //Get the swapped values
    for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tested it. Let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: That was really helpful I understood everything but I have a small question. Imagine x = 0 so If you say string[x] that would be the first sentence from the array. Now, why do you say strings[x][i] it would be the letter of the sentence if I understand.

Comment: @Stackingc Yeah. strings[2][3] means get third letter of second string( indexes start from 0 ). I think you should read more about multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Thank you, bro. I really appreciate! Check this out https://imgur.com/a/6CFN5 and let me know.

Comment: @Stackingc Its pretty cool. (and correct)

Answer (score 1):

Why 5D array, `char strings[5][5][5][5][5]`  ? you just want to 5 strings as input So for this take 2D array

`char strings[5][4]`;// total 5 strings , in each you can stores 4 characters.

Next things How will you scan data for 2D arrays, you need to rotate two loops namely for rows and columns . Assume `row = 5` & `col = 4`

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &strings[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Next this       `temp[b_value] = strings[a_value];` statement you need to modify, modify according your requirement.
I hope this helps.